# Hive describe shows partition also as column but describe formatted doesn't

Tags: hive, cloudera-cdh, hue, hive-partitions

Hive table created:

```
create external table ini(id string, rand string) partitioned by (tmp string)
```

Describe:

```
describe ini;
```

Output from hue:

[image: describe output]

Describe formatted:

```
describe formatted ini;
```

Output from hue:

[image: describe-formatted output]

Why is the partition column shown in column list in hive `describe` table?
`describe formatted` seems to show it correctly.